# How could I intercept a save scene action being run in Unity?

Tags: unity, events, savegame, scene

How could I intercept a save scene action being run in Unity?

There is some code I would like to run in editor whenever a scene is saved. Is it possible for me to detect somehow when a scene is saved?

Comment: Something like https://answers.unity.com/questions/175931/perform-action-on-saveload-in-editor.html?

Comment: @Zibelas, thanks it is helpful. I never even heard about the `AssetModificationProcessor`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unity already has a built-in event for doing exactly what you want: [`EditorSceneManager.sceneSaving`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager-sceneSaving.html)

Usage:

```
EditorSceneManager.sceneSaving += OnSavingScene;

private void OnSavingScene(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.Scene scene, string path) {
    //do some stuff here
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark scene objects you modify as dirty with `EditorUtility.SetDirty(myObjectOrComponent)` otherwise those changes will not be reflected in your scene change.